# Adding multiple recipients using google api in python?

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have been using the guides for the gmail api to create drafts. The following code has been working well.

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):

  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

My question is, how do I add multiple recipients? The API guides seem to not mention anything of the sort.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`MIMEText` expects a string of comma separated recipients:

```
message['to'] = 'me@gmail.com, you@gmail.com'
```